# Where to leave luggage in Gdansk?

Tags: luggage, poland, gdansk

Is there another place than the station to leave luggage in Gdansk, Poland?

I was in the station, and there were around 10 lockers all full. I am not sure if I was in the right place though. I am not sure I was in the right place and I didn't have oportunity to check again. I will need to leave luggage for one day and I was wondering if either there was another place or even if the station has more lockers that I did not see.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to go to a hostel and ask them.  For example, Hostel Zappio (I believe that's the one I stayed in, but I'm not sure) - [it shows online as having luggage storage](http://www.hostelz.com/hostel/163562-Hostel-Zappio).  Yes, in theory that's for guests staying there, but I've asked shops and hostels/hotels to look after bags for me in the past, and sometimes they've done it for free, sometimes for a small fee.  And if it's just a small fee, it may well be worth it for you to try.

Comment: Works in Gdansk for not-popular hostels, can't say names for now.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Gdanks, as I discovered later, there are plenty of luggage lockers. It just happens that I exited through the "wrong" side of the station (via the bus terminal) where they have at most 10 lockers (and they were all full).

**Additional information**

On the main entrance of the station there are several lockers. It seems to be busy since most of them were full. There are more lockers downstairs though.

Answer (score 2):

There is a luggage storage point in the city centre 
https://plus.google.com/107594251083173710256/about?gl=pl&hl=pl

Comment: Welcome! It's best not to just post links, but to include the detail in the links as well - like the address or whatever of the storage point.  That way if the link goes down, the info is still available for future users...