# Is there a website or resource with tips of places where to leave luggage?

Tags: luggage-storage

Based on this [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/33696/where-to-leave-luggage-in-gdansk/36465#36465) I started wondering in which options are available to leave luggage.

It's a common problem when travelling and the most usual places are either in a locker (at airports, train stations) or luggage rooms (at the hotel/hostel). It wouldn't be the first time though where the place where I stay doesn't keep luggage, the prices of the lockers are prohibitive or they don't exist.

I wonder if there is some resource with tips to leave luggage safe and/or affordably.

Eg.: I once met a guy that used to leave his luggage in hotel lobbies. He just left it there and it never disappeared. Worst case scenario, someone from the hotel would pick it up and put it behind the counter. This was a long time a ago. Nowadays you might get your luggage exploded thinking its a bomb :)

Comment: In which country? I doubt there is a **global** left luggage web site!

Comment: You raise a good point . For now I seek a guide with examples, like the one in the linked answer. I don't expect leave it at place X (though that's a good idea too) but more of - "ask in a shop, etc." But I expect a bit more ingenious ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Luggage storage is now a big business, and it's not hard to query it, just google LUGGAGE STORAGE SERVICES followed by place where you are going. It's impossible to give you an exact guidance since it varies on location rates...

Comment: No doubt it's a big business. Thanks for the tip, but I am looking for more out of the usual schemes. Sometimes those places are just too expensive to leave luggage for half an hour or so.

Comment: ah ok didn't know that was actually your target...